# How to read Kubernets secrets values

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

What could be the `kubectl` command to see `k8s` `secret` values

I tried

```
kubectl get secrets/<secrets-name> -n <namespace>
```

It returns

```
NAME            TYPE     DATA   AGE
secrets1        Opaque   1      18h
```

but I want to know what value stored inside the secret

Answer (score 2):

So the answer was so simple I just have to add  `-o jsonpath='{.data}'` at the end of the command

```
kubectl get secrets/<secrets-name> -n <namespace>  -o jsonpath='{.data}'
```